# Equally Marginalize a Left-Aligned Size-Changing Box w/ Image Container in CSS/SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation, styling

Here's the challenge. I have a left-aligned text container (width: 40%;) that changes height with the window. I need my right half of the screen set as an image container (width: 60%) to which the image centers horizontally in the container, and vertically with the center of the text container.

Here is what my current code is doing:
[image: website-current]

Here is what I would like it to do:
[image: website-goal]

I'm barely savvy in JS, so I'm trying to avoid it pending the need for tweaks. Here is my current code for the section:

```css
.design-portfolio {
 position: relative;
 .web-img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  .web-img-lg {
   img {
    max-height: 40em;
   }
  }
 }
 .web-img-sm {
  @media (min-width:75.063em) {
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
  }
 }
 .web-design-box {
  @media (min-width:75.063em) {
   $font-title: 25px NexaBook;
   $font-sub-title: 25px NexaHeavy;
   $font-copy-title: 20px NexaHeavy;
   $font-copy: 20px NexaBook;
   position: relative;
   width: 40%;
   padding-right: 2em;
   .size-fix {
    position: relative;
   }
   .bg-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $pink;
    top: 2em;
    bottom: 2em;
    left: 0;
    right: -2em;
   }
   .border-box {
    position: relative;
    border: .3em solid $black;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 3em;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    .h1 {
     font: $font-title;
     color: $white;
     text-align: right;
    }
    .h2 {
     font: $font-sub-title;
     text-align: right;
    }
    .copy {
     font: $font-copy;
     color: $white;
     text-align: left;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     .h3 {
      font: $font-copy-title;
      color: $white;
      text-align: left;
     }
    }
    .copy p {
     line-height: 1.2;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="web-img-container">
  <div class="web-img-lg">
   <img src="assets/img/website-design.png" alt="web-design">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="web-design-box">
  <div class="size-fix">
   <div class="bg-box"></div>
   <div class="border-box">
    <div class="h1">
     my approach on
    </div>
    <div class="h2">
     website design
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="copy">
     <div class="h3">purpose</div>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     </p>
     <div class="h3">simplicity</div>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     </p>
     <div class="h3">mobile first</div>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

I don't know how to set it up to run, as it's in SASS rather than regular CSS. :/

Comment: Please set it up the right way. It's too messy. No one will try to help if you gave a messy code.

Comment: Could you explain what about it needs cleaned up? I apologize as I am a designer first and fairly new to development.

Comment: Change you scss to css. So, your code will run to the stackoverflow snippet.